# getActionBar() is always returning null

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I have gone through lots of similar posts in Stackoverflow, but nothing seems to resolve my issue.

I am trying to get the `ActionBar` and invoke `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`.

I can see the black ActionBar (as the theme is black background) with the Activity name displayed as title. But in my activity code, if I try to do `getActionBar()` it always returns null.

I tried the code in `onResume()` and `onCreate()` (after inflating the layout). Everywhere it returns null. Is there anything I am missing?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityMain"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

This is my styles definition. I am using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Also, I am using following dependency:

```
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

and my activity class definition is:

```
MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: try getSupportActionBar() instead of getActionBar()

Comment: did you try using getSupportActionBar().  The latest appcompat-v7 seems to disable the systembar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using getSupportActionBar(). The latest appcompat-v7 seems to disable the systembar.

Answer (score 1):

If your class defenition is `MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity`, you should try using [getSupportActionBar()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#getSupportActionBar())

If your class defenition is `MainActivity extends Activity`, you can try using [getActionBar()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getActionBar()) (this call requires API 11)

Comment: Thank you for your time. I am using AppCompatActivity.